# About displacement under screen edge

Tags: android, view, sdk

Is there any early implemented way, to hide View in WindowManager under screen edge.?

[Like this.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9o68c87xpq0bz5v/ex_sc.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
view.setTranslationX(parent.getMeasuredWidth() - visiblePixelsX);
view.setTranslationY(parent.getMeasuredHeight() - visiblePixelsY);
```

Where `parent` is the `ViewGroup` your view is nested inside, and `visiblePixelsX/Y` is the amount in pixels you'd like to still remain visible of the view.